# Calculating effective mass of electron from energy band diagram

Tags: mass, semiconductor-physics, electronic-band-theory

How can I calculate the effective mass of electron in the conduction band of silicon with the approximation that they are free, from its energy band diagram by my hand - not software or something else?

Comment: What do you know about how effective mass is defined and calculated? How have you tried to apply this to your problem? What references have you already consulted to try to answer this question?

Comment: @ThePhoton I know that effective mass is h^2(d^2E/dk^2)^-1. So I need to calculate second derivation of E diagram with respect to k. But how can I do this by hand solution?

Comment: The way you worded the question implies you know the "energy band diagram". So if you have E(k) as a formula, you take the 2nd derivative of that formula, invert it and multiply by $h^2$.

Comment: If you don't have a formula from which a 2nd derivative can be calculated, then you aren't going to be able to get a hand-calculated effective mass.

Comment: No I just have diagram. No formula. But professor said that calculate it from the energy band diagram that you found in the literature. I am so confused.

Comment: Usually all we know about the band diagram is the first 2 terms of the Taylor expansion for E(k), so it's easy to get the 2nd derivative. (And realistically, we got the Taylor terms by measuring the effective mass, so the question you've been asked is really backwards from how the parameters are determined experimentally)

Comment: Can you share the diagram you were given?

Comment: By the way, you asked the same question on EE.SE. Please don't post duplication questions on SE sites until you've given some time (24 hours at least) for the question to be answered on the first site and you didn't get an adequate answer.

Comment: Perhaps you could manually calculate the second derivative of E wrt k by obtaining numerical values from the diagram. This might be of use: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654507/numerically-calculate-the-second-left-hand-derivative

Comment: @ThePhoton Actually he did not give any diagram. He asked us to find from the literature. Here is the link that I found: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/96316/what-does-number-of-lines-represent-in-semiconductors-e-k-diagram

Answer (score 0):

Fundamentally, you need to somehow fit a parabola to the conduction band minimum and find the second derivative of the parabola. How you do this depends on the tools at your disposal. If it's truly pencil, paper, and a ruler only, then you'll only be able to get a very rough answer. (Think: how many points are needed to uniquely define a parabola.) If you can use a tool like datatheif to digitize the figure, then you can fit much more accurately.

Also, note that Si has an anisotropic effective mass, so you'll have to do this procedure (at least) twice.